# Parsing a variable in shell scripting

Tags: linux, shell

I am new to shell scripting just started off.
I have written this script

```
 #!/bin/sh
 profile_type= cat /www/data/profile.conf
 echo $profile_type
```

the o/p of this script is

```
. /tmp/S_panicA1.txt
. /tmp/S_panicA0.txt

 away_Def="panicA1 panicA0"
 away_Byp=0
 away_Sts=$((panicA1+panicA0-away_Byp))
```

In this i want to get panicA1 panicA0 and 0 and store it in other variable how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to assign the output of a command to a variable, you use the dollar parenthesis syntax.

```
foo=$(cat /my/file)
```

You can also use the backticks syntax.

```
foo=`cat /my/file`
```

---

In your script, you simply run the command `cat` and assign its result, nothing, to your variable. Hence the output consisting of the content of your file, result of `cat`, followed by an empty line, result of `echo` with an empty variable.

Comment: how to parse that variable so i can get panicA1 panicA0 and 0 into another variable

Comment: Got to know a bit more: What is the actual content of the file? What do you want to parse? How many variables do you want?